# NodeJs lwip.open() callback function returns empty object on reading a image file from disk

Tags: node.js, image-processing, lwip

> lwip.open() returns an empty object on reading a image from the disk
>   and am using lwip version "0.0.6"

**NodeJs Code:**

```
var lwip = require('lwip');
lwip.open('path/to/image.jpg', function(err, image){
 console.log("Image :", image); 
});
```

**OUTPUT:**

> Image : {__lwip: {}, __locked: false, __trans: false }

Answer (score 0):

> Though the callback function throws an empty object {__lwip: {}, __locked: false, __trans: false }, write the callback image to a location to view the image once you complete the image manipulation operations...

**NodeJs Example Code:**

```
var lwip = require('lwip');    
require('lwip').open('image.jpg', function(err, image){          
  image.batch()
    .scale(0.75)          // scale to 75%
    .rotate(45, 'white')  // rotate 45degs clockwise (white fill)
    .crop(200, 200)       // crop a 200X200 square from center
    .blur(5)              // Gaussian blur with SD=5
    .writeFile('output.jpg', function(err){
      // check err...
      // done.
    });    
});
```